# Heredoc en PHP devuelve Error: Undefined variable: usando sprintf

Tags: php

Defino el contenido de una variable en `PHP` usando `HEREDOC`

```
$ptrn = <<<EOF
En %2$s se ha bebido %1$d cervezas!
EOF;
```

Cuando intento formatear con `sprinf`

```
$ptrn = sprintf($ptrn,7,"Paco");
```

me devuelve el siguiente error

> Notice: Undefined variable: s in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\androidtemplates\test.php on line 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usás `<<<EOF`..`EOF;` ([sintaxis heredoc](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)) las variables son interpretadas -de la misma forma que si fueran comillas (`"`).

Para evitarlo se puede usar la [sintaxis nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) que actúa como comillas simples (`'`).

```
$ptrn = <<<'EOF'
En %2$s se ha bebido %1$d cervezas!
EOF;
```